# Recommended laptop models for Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid)

Tags: 10.04, laptop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which computers are guaranteed to work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131/which-computers-are-guaranteed-to-work-with-ubuntu)

I am thinking of purchasing a new laptop computer and will be installing Ubuntu Lucid Desktop (either 64-bit or 32-bit) on it. What models can you recommend?