# Which new Dell laptops will run Ubuntu 10.10 with full hardware compatibility?

Tags: hardware, compatibility

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which computers are guaranteed to work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131/which-computers-are-guaranteed-to-work-with-ubuntu)

My parent's laptop is slowly grinding to a halt and they are looking at buying something new. Does anybody know which of Dell's current laptop selection would offer full hardware support under Ubuntu 10.10? Any advice or guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Have you seen the hardware certification database run by Canonical? It lists all Dell (and other manufacturer) models which are certified.

http://webapps.ubuntu.com/certification/

The following link takes you right to the Dell entries.

http://webapps.ubuntu.com/certification/make/Dell/

Comment: I had already looked at the database but couldn't find any Inspiron models that correspond with those on offer on the Dell UK website at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a specific reason for purchasing Dell, you might find that buying a laptop with Ubuntu on it already better: you are guaranteed that the laptop is supported then. Vendors such as http://zareason.com/shop/Laptops/ and http://www.system76.com/ sell laptops with Ubuntu on.

Dell's lineup of laptops which they sell with Ubuntu on them out of the box changes frequently, but http://dell.com/ubuntu lists a laptop, a netbook, and a desktop machine at the moment.

Comment: I had considered system76 but I am based in the UK and it seems they don't distribute over here... thanks anyway.