# Is a Dell Inspiron 13z compatible with Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: ati, inspiron

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which computers are guaranteed to work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131/which-computers-are-guaranteed-to-work-with-ubuntu)

I'm thinking about buying a Dell Inspiron 13z - I basically want a small, light laptop for programming while I travel to and from work.

I'm just looking for reassurance that all of the hardware is supported.

Spec from http://www1.ap.dell.com/au/en/home/notebooks/inspiron-13z-intel/pd.aspx?refid=inspiron-13z-intel&s=dhs&cs=audhs1&~ck=mn

Intel  Core  i5-470UM (1.33GHz, turbo boost up to 1.86Ghz, 3M cache)
Standard 4GB (2 X 2 GB) 2 DIMM DDR3 1333Mhz

Chipset: Intel®  HM57
Graphics: ATI Mobility RadeonTM  HD5430 - 1GB
Wireless: Dell Wireless 1501 802.11b/g/n Half Mini Card (standard)

Thanks.

Comment: The 13z is not mentioned in any of the links in that question. So my question remains unanswered.