# How do I know if a laptop will work with Ubuntu?

Tags: hardware, compatibility

I want to buy a laptop at some point in the near future, but not knowing beforehand whether it works with Ubuntu makes the whole operation risky and tiresome. I would like to know if there is some kind of official hardware database where I can enter the name of the laptop I'm interested in and see if it's 100% compatible out of the box, or in case it isn't what is it exactly that doesn't work (ideally also if there is a way to fix it).

Does Canonical have a project along these lines?

Comment: I found that system76.com sells hardware with Ubuntu installed on it. Go to see www.system76.com

Comment: Related: [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu) and [Where can I find a list of computers guaranteed to work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-computers-guaranteed-to-work-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When I bought mine, I simply brought a live CD in the store, and asked to try it on their laptops. I explained them what this is, and that I want to check the compatibility of the different components with Ubuntu. I sometime had to explain what Ubuntu was...... One place told me a flat NO, that I could  not try it. I ran out of the store as fast as I could. At the store where I actually bought my portable (in Dec. 2006), I tested that the display was actually working on the internal monitor, at the full resolution, as advertised on the spec sheet, that the wireless adapter was found, and that I could use the card reader, with a card I brought in. I finally tested the sound itself, which was rather easy to do.

Today, you could bring Linux on a USB disk instead, or even an SD card. Also, in 2010, you should expect every sales rep on the floor to be at least know about Linux. Usually, they should understand that starting it from a CD, especially if this is a branded one, not burned at home, there is no harm that will be done on the machine.

NOTE: The fact that some components are not discovered right at boot from a live CD does not mean that Ubuntu will not support it. Chances are that you will find the proper driver for it.  You will just have some manual setup to do.

You may also want to note the brand names and models from a store and check on the net, with Google. You should usually find either some test cases or message exchange about it that will give you a good idea about the model you are looking for.

Comment: I agree with everything other then taking a live cd/usb/sd card to a store... while in principal there is nothing wrong with this but the odds of finding a store that will let you do this are slim to none, Consider that most minimum wage floor associates will know little to none about the products they are trying to sell, and that information they get from in-store pamphlets they they are trained with... This isn't to say it isn't worth a shot, you might get a floor associate that is more then knowledgeable on the subject, just saying I wouldn't get to upset if they say no.

Comment: Actually, two stores out of the three I tried actually accepted to let me do it. I think the trick is to be able to talk with a rep who knows about Linux. In 2006, Linux was not as known as it is in 2010. I consider that a sales rep who does not know Linux should not even be hired. Although Linux is not THE market leader in OS, it should no more be ignored.

Comment: +1 for taking the live CD/usb stick to the store. I recently did that to buy my sister's laptop, 1 store said no (went out directly) and the second said yes. I checked that all was working fine, and bought it from them. You loose nothing from trying, and you're even participating in some word-spreading if the vendor does not know about Ubuntu.

Comment: Is there a compatibility software that I can run to test that ubuntu is fully compatible ? I may forget one point or too while I'm testing it live at a store

Comment: AFAIK there is no one software that checks your laptop for Ubuntu compatibility. As mentioned above, use the live CD / USB to test it on a new system.

Comment: "When I bought mine, I simply brought a live CD in the store, and asked to try it on their laptops." --- When I did in my store, they refused, rightfully reasoning about the costs to re-install Windows in case it would fail.

Answer (score 9):

This will help you: [Ubuntu hardware partners](https://partners.ubuntu.com/programmes/hardware)

See also:

- [Which computers are guaranteed to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131/which-computers-are-guaranteed-to-work-with-ubuntu)

Comment: Thanks aneeshep, that webpage doesn't show many laptops because it seems to only have officially tested hardware, right? Is it possible to see community-provided info?

Comment: Even community information may be erroneous as some manufacturers change specifications or hardware components within a series. Best advice is to check with a live CD at your local dealer before you buy it.

Comment: Indeed! Also, for future reference, could you list what specific items one should check while testing the laptop?

Comment: @Bou # 1: Yes, this list only shows a limited range of manufacturers, but it's showing you which manufacturers *actively support Ubuntu* by submitting their laptops to be tested by Canonical. My laptop is on that list and Ubuntu 10.04 worked on it straight away, including sound, WiFi, hotkeys, ...

Answer (score 3):

While I upvoted the idea of trying out a LiveCD or LiveUSBStick, if you can't do it at your favorite store, here are some thoughts...

You might check on Craigslist - there are some great deals on year-old laptops, and if you're carrying cash, an individual might be more willing to let you test Ubuntu on it.

If you really want to buy new, and you can't test, my experience doing many dozens of Ubuntu installs over the last five years says there are only a few things you're likely to have problems with:

1. Multiple drives in a weird fakeraid configuration - I'm looking at you, Sony. You can prevent this by making sure the laptop only has one hard drive. (For more details, look [here](http://bobertville.blogspot.com/2008/11/triple-boot-sony-vaio-vgn-ar-notebook.html) and [here](http://bobertville.blogspot.com/2008/12/triple-boot-sony-vaio-vgn-ar-notebook.html).)
2. Bleeding edge wi-fi or Ethernet controllers; sometimes it takes a while for support for those to make it into the Linux kernel. There are compatibility lists, and in any case, if a laptop's controller chips are from a major manufacturer (e.g. Broadcom, Intel, etc.) and have been out for a year, you should be okay.
3. Bleeding edge GPU. Same as for the wi-fi and Ethernet controllers; the manufacturer names are just different.

I've never had a Ubuntu compatibility problem with a reasonably modern x86 CPU, motherboard, memory, etc. It even ran fine on my creaking old 2000-era HP laptop before I recycled it. So I'd guesstimate that if a laptop passes 1-3, chances are 99+% it will be fine with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

This may also help you.

http://www.linux-laptop.net/

Answer (score 1):

*As it was [written in another answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/389176/is-there-a-database-of-linux-compatible-hardware/739742#739742) by [linuxbuild](https://askubuntu.com/users/51737/linuxbuild):*

> A database of Linux-compatible computers & devices:
> https://linux-hardware.org/
>
> Timeline of tested computers:
> https://linux-hardware.org/?view=timeline
>
> A tool to analyze and count your computer:
> https://github.com/linuxhw/hw-probe
>
> [image]