# Is there a database of Linux compatible hardware?

Tags: hardware, compatibility, community

I want to know if there is a centralised community site where all Hardware is listed in terms of compatability with Linux. Something **like AppDB for Wine**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Centralized, I don't think so.

But maybe this one is something you are looking for:

- [Linux Hardware Compatibility Lists & Linux Drivers](http://linux-drivers.org/)

There are some other sites:

- [Ubuntu Certified hardware](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/)
- the sticky posts here: [Ubuntu Forums: Hardware](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=332)
- [Debian Hardware Portal](https://wiki.debian.org/Hardware)

For laptops:

- [Linux Laptop Wiki](http://www.linlap.com/)
- [Linux on Laptops](http://www.linux-laptop.net/)

And an older list:

- [Linux Hardware Compatibility HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Hardware-HOWTO/)

And most likely there are compatibility lists on every major distributions' site/forum, and some specialized sites like for TV-tuners:

- [Hardware device information - LinuxTVWiki](http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Hardware_Device_Information)

Comment: I also found this http://community.linuxmint.com/hardware/

Answer (score 7):

A database of Linux-compatible computers & devices: https://linux-hardware.org/

Timeline of tested computers: https://linux-hardware.org/?view=timeline

A tool to analyze and count your computer: https://github.com/linuxhw/hw-probe

[image]

I'm the author of this project, so feel free to ask any questions in comments!

Answer (score 1):

[Linux Hardware Guide](http://www.linux-hardware-guide.com/) looks like a good resource.