# Not being able to install Ubuntu or any linux distros

Tags: dual-boot, usb

I wanted to install Ubuntu the other day, but when I tried to install it to my drive, it would go with the installer and stop, and say "Cannot install grub to /dev/sda" or stuff like that, I'd click Dont install the bootloader, since I have rEFInd, but then the installer would crash, and then the USB would crash in a PCIEport bus error refreshing list, I tried installing other distros too like Elementary OS and deepin, both had the same issue, even if deepin only got stuck at 62%, I need a solution as I really want to dual boot

Comment: I didnt know of that, I'll try that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

1) Nowdays, most of the recent hardware are Linux compatibility. But still kindly check your hardware compatibility with Linux. Kindly refer the below link:

[Is There A Database of Linux compatible hardware?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/389176/is-there-a-database-of-linux-compatible-hardware)

2) If it is compatibility, follow the installation process in below link:

[How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)