# Intel Xeon E compability with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, intel

I just want to confirm before buying a new computer that the processor is compatible with Ubuntu 16.04.
The processor: https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/191035/intel-xeon-e-2276g-processor-12m-cache-3-80-ghz.html

How can I check if this processor is compatible with the Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: You can check [this link](https://browser.geekbench.com/v4/cpu/search?dir=desc&page=2&q=Xeon+&sort=score): the same processor is tested with Linux (they didn't mention the distro). So I think that intel xeon e-2276g works fine with Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 too.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the answer! I'll save that link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, the intel processor type is the least of your worries when installing in a new computer.  as an example, graphics chips can often be problematic.  [linux-hardware.org](https://linux-hardware.org) is a good place to start, as well as others.

You will probably need to disable secure boot, so check with the manufacturer's site.

See also this answer:
[Is there a database of Linux compatible hardware?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/389176/is-there-a-database-of-linux-compatible-hardware)

Comment: Search results for Xeon E in the database: https://linux-hardware.org/?view=search&name=Xeon+E-2#list

Comment: window mgrs other than kde have similar tools.  also, unless you have a good reason to use 16.04, you might consider using 18.04 - it's the current LTS (long term support) version.