# How to determine if a computer will be able to run Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, system-installation, hardware

What is the process someone should go through when trying to determine if a computer will be able to run linux? I assume the first step is to look to see if the computer is certified (e.g. on https://ubuntu.com/certified), but what if the computer is new, is not on that list, or is self-built.

In this case I would assume you should look at the relevant parts and ask if they are compatible? If so what is a list of parts that should be checked in order to do your due diligence? Where is the best place to check these? Is there anything else that should be checked to make sure the parts will all work together?

Assume the user has a list of parts, but not a physical device to test it on. What is required to do a sensible due diligence?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a database of Linux compatible hardware?](https://askubuntu.com/q/389176/)

Comment: I have come across https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar and it was a surface level answer to what I was wanting. But what I'm wanting is a deeper answer that explains how to analyse potential hardware from the parts or what must I consider, more what do I need to check from my hardware and less which version should I install.

Comment: If you can borrow a machine; you can boot *live* media & test it out & get a pretty good clue as to what will work, and what may take some work etc... eg. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install  I borrow people's machines to perform QA testing, as I boot *live* media, and when I'm done I reboot & remove media & the owners OS on ssd/drive boots normally (*at worst their clock may have adjusted to UTC time*)

Comment: FYI:  Ubuntu LTS releases come with kernel stacks; and media is available with *five* different kernel stacks for 20.04 (*5.4, 5.8, 5.11, 5.13 & 5.15 kernels*), or for later 22.04 (5.15 & 5.19; 6.2 will be available soon; it can be installed but doesn't yet exist on *live* downloadable media; but you can use 23.04 media for a *live* test currently of that) so *live* testing can provide some good testing if you plan.

Comment: @guiverc , that would definitely be my first go-to if possible, unfortunately its one of the newer/more expensive ones I'm looking at so I don't expect to be able to test one out. But I figured doing due diligence, then buy and live test if the due diligence comes back positive then install if everything is working. But I figured this would be a good time to determine what is due diligence (going from using Ubuntu and knowing the basics to wanting to dig deeper into it)

Comment: It seems like you are essentially asking how to check each component to see if it is supported by the Linux kernel. That's well beyond "due dilligence" for most end users. Ordinary testing using a newer kernel in a newer live media (the "Try Ubuntu" environment) is sufficient. Bleeding-edge hardware may take a year or more before it is supported by the kernel, depending upon the manufacturer. Advice: Purchase from a vendor with a generous return policy.

Comment: @user535733 Your last comment to me is the key concept. It's not even possible to keep an updated database of all Linux-compatible computer hardware components because the database is dependent on the existence of drivers which usually appear within a year of when the hardware was launched in the marketplace. Maintaining a database of compatible laptops is possible however.