# Which netbooks are "safe to buy"?

Tags: hardware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which computers are guaranteed to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131/which-computers-are-guaranteed-to-work)

To have a lightweight computer I would like to buy a netbook. Are there any netbooks especially suiting Ubuntu? For example, I have read that Unity causes problems on some machines, which I would like to avoid.