# What recent netbooks, as of April 2011, are known to work properly with Ubuntu?

Tags: hardware, compatibility

I'm looking for netbooks that work properly with Ubuntu, i.e. don't have wireless problems, graphics problems, touchpad problems etc.  Ideally these would be netbooks that have come out recently, and first-hand experience is best, though links to detailed information are okay as well.  Resources like [Ubuntu-certified hardware](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/) seem quite out of date--I'm looking for recent ubuntu-friendly netbooks.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/12821/which-netbooks-are-safe-to-buy

Comment: The most recent answers there are from November of 2010, and non-specific.  I'm looking for answers like the ones below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which computers are guaranteed to work?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/131/which-computers-are-guaranteed-to-work)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a hardware shopping recommendation request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this](http://www.system76.com/product_info.php?cPath=28&products_id=105) one is the best when it comes to ubuntu.

Comment: Very cool--nice find!

Answer (score 0):

My Asus EeePC 900HA works flawlessly - almost - I do have a question on here about getting wireless working again after I use Fn+F2. Otherwise, as I said, it works flawlessly. Other EeePCs therefore should work correctly.

The only minor annoyance is occasionally the mouse will jump when you press the touchpad, but it's a small annoyance.

(P.S. I'm using Mint LXDE right now, but I was using Ubuntu Netbook remix. I did turn Unity off though, major resource hog, and major annoyance to use)