# Who makes laptops for Ubuntu?

Tags: hardware

I'm looking for a laptop and would like to avoid the whole 'is this [specific configuration of hardware] compatible with Ubuntu?' process by finding a laptop manufactured with Ubuntu in mind.

I know of [system76](http://www.system76.com/), but are there any other manufacturers making laptops built to run a **standard build** of Ubuntu?

*I'm not counting Dell, as - from my experience - their 'Ubuntu' laptops/netbooks require their build, and because of that have their own set of compatibility issues. UPDATE: And as mentioned in the comments, Dell is no longer selling systems with Ubuntu to consumers.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which computers are guaranteed to work?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/131/which-computers-are-guaranteed-to-work)

Comment: @Jorge Yeah, it's close - but that (at least the answer) includes compatibility lists/testing, which I'm trying to avoid by finding a laptop manufacturer targeting Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean by "manufacturer".  I know System76 doesn't *manufacture* anything -- they build and validate the systems as working.  I believe the same is true of Zareason.

Comment: Indeed, system76 and ZaReason don't manufacture their own laptops.  Same can be said of Dell, HP, Gateway, Sony and many others (in some cases they make make some models and contract out others).  It's a weird industry:  http://www.mopo.ca/real-laptop-manufacturers.html

Comment: I understand that most manufactures don't actually 'manufacture' what they're selling. The aim of my question is finding vendors that are selling hardware that is designed to work with a normal distribution of Ubuntu (not requiring some crazy wireless driver, or a patched video driver, or insane suspend crashes). I'm assuming that since system76 is selling exclusively 'Ubuntu' systems, they make sure the hardware they use works well with Ubuntu (I may be wrong there). That's the kind of 'manufacturers' I'm looking for.

Comment: @Tim -- according to EvilPhoenix, Dell doesn't even sell Ubuntu-certified systems now (aside from servers, I think).

Comment: @Tim: I meant standard computers for the end-user, not for server setups.

Comment: @Tim.  Indeed.  Fwiw, system76 does have customizations but they are all included in a single deb (for all models).  So I'm not positive it meets your requirements, but it is very much simple to manage.  I did a fresh install of 10.10 and didn't actually notice any issues on mine before adding the sys76 driver back on (which I did eventually), but will very by model.  See: http://knowledge76.com/index.php/System76_Driver

Comment: In my expirience, all laptops/desktops can run ubuntu. I don't know of any laptop/desktop manufactured with ubuntu in mind, since most of the companies have an agreement with microsoft, therefore, all windows based. But its all about the drivers really....
And I have a dell laptop(my neighbours wanted to trow it away, and I asked can I have it just to fool arround with it :P) and ubuntu runs just fine on it. I never had to install special drivers on any of the systems I put ubuntu on, I only found it impossible to run amd graphic card drivers...... Hope that helps?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I FOUND IT- Here is a detailed list (by help.ubuntu.com) with all of the vendors (apparently) that have ubuntu pre-installed and what type of computers they sell with ubuntu pre-installed. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuPre-installed

Answer (score 13):

[System 76](http://system76.com) and [Zareason](http://www.zareason.com) are the big two with [Dell](http://www.dell.com/ubuntu) only really giving Ubuntu token offerings. Depending on your location and requirements have a look at these sites:

- [LinuxPreloaded](http://linuxpreloaded.com/)
- [Laptops/Notebooks with Linux Preinstalled](http://mcelrath.org/laptops.html)

Answer (score 10):

[**ZaReason**](http://zareason.com) .

> Building computers that are optimized to work with Linux distributions including Ubuntu, Fedora, Trisquel and others!

[image]

Reviews

[ZaReason Teo Pro Netbook: Test Drive Ready for Takeoff](http://www.thevarguy.com/2011/03/04/zareason-teo-pro-netbook-test-drive-ready-for-takeoff/)

[ZaReason Terra HD](http://ubuntulinuxtipstricks.blogspot.com/2010/08/zareason-terra-hd.html)

[On Zareason](http://www.jonobacon.org/2010/08/28/on-zareason/)

[My ZaReason Laptop](http://www.nixternal.com/my-zareason-laptop/)

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I'm a fan of system76 and own a Pangolin Performance myself.  Their support is excellent as well as their policies.  Heck, they have [their own forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=341) on [Ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/).  Outside of system76, however, the vendor you want to look at is [ZaReason](http://zareason.com/).

ZaReason offers their laptops pre-installed with Ubuntu, Kubuntu, or Edubuntu in both 10.04 and 10.10 editions, as well as Linux Mint 10, Debian 5, and Fedora 14.  I've heard only positive things about them as a company and about their products.  Definitely worth checking out.

Comment: They look good - I'm not trying to avoid system76, just want to get a better idea of what's out there.

Answer (score 6):

## The handcrafted [Steampunk notebook](http://www.datamancer.net/steampunklaptop/steampunklaptop.htm) for 5000$

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow! This is a real artwork! Technology with soul!

Comment: The company doesn't appear to sell laptops anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Dell has ties with Ubuntu ; here is a link on the Dell website with more information:
[Dell/Ubuntu](http://www.dell.com/ubuntu) .

Comment: However (as I mentioned in the question) - Dell doesn't seem interested in creating hardware that can run Ubuntu - they're interested in creating their own Ubuntu that can run on their hardware.

Comment: @Tim I guess I'm not following you on your Dell comments.  Are you saying you had a Dell, and couldn't install a different version of Ubuntu on it?  I've liked some Dells and disliked others (likewise with every vendor I can think of), but I've never had an issue running Ubuntu on a Dell beyond the occasional wifi driver issues common to Linux systems at the time.

Comment: Dell stopped production of machines that are shipped with Ubuntu.  They've stopped this for a while now.

Comment: @jgbelacqua, the Dells I've used came with a very customized install - which *didn't* (that I could find) update through Ubuntu's repositories, and couldn't do a distribution upgrade. Even in the 'certified' list, many Dell's are only certified for the pre-installed OS, not a standard Ubuntu distribution.

Comment: @Tim  Yeah, I guess I'm focused more on the fact that I've always had success running Ubuntu, whether or not the machine has been certified by Dell to actually run Ubuntu (for that version).

Comment: @EvilPhoenix -- well, that would seem to rule out Dell....  They do have servers certified for Ubuntu, but I don't know if that's relevant here.  http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/make/Dell/servers

Comment: @Tim: See my comment far above.

Comment: @EvilPhoenix Yeah, I noticed that I can't even select Ubuntu as an OS anymore. @jgbelacqua The issues I've had have been with their netbooks, perhaps their laptops use more generally compatible hardware (I wouldn't be surprised at that).

Comment: @Tim: I've got a business-line Dell Latitude E6500 with Ubuntu 10.04 on it, it works with 99% compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

HP certifies their business laptops with SLED (Suse Linux Enterprise Desktop). Not Ubuntu, but it's the same kernel, so hardware-wise things will be fine.

You can configure FreeDOS or SLED pre-installed depending on the model.

[Linux certification and support matrix - 
HP notebooks](http://h20338.www2.hp.com/enterprise/cache/569891-0-0-0-121.html) .

Answer (score 3):

Also consider using [ThinkPenguin](http://libre.thinkpenguin.com/).

Not only will their products work with Ubuntu, they will work with other free as in freedom software too, as the components have been selected to require no proprietary drivers.

Think Penguin actively supports free software, and by inserting libre into the front of their url, your purchase on their website will result in a donation of part of the profit to the free software project [Trisquel](https://trisquel.info/en). ThinkPenguin is endorsed by the [Free Software  Foundation](http://www.fsf.org/resources/), though the project receives no money from this endorsement.

(Trisquel is based on Ubuntu, but uses the linux-libre kernel instead and removes all non free as in freedom repositories / software.

Other companies endorsed by the FSF which should have computers that can run GNU/Linux distributions in general are:

- [Freedom Included](http://freedomincluded.com/)
- [Lemote](http://www.lemote.com/en/)
- [Zareason](http://zareason.com/shop/home.php?cat=)
- [Los Alamos Computers](http://laclinux.com/en/Start)
- [Garlach44](http://www.garlach44.eu/en/)
- [Inatux](http://www.inatux.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Check out [OMG UBUNTU's](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/?p=16282) list of notebooks and netbooks that comes with Ubuntu preinstalled.

I personally like the MeeNee 13.1″ Pro (black); clean and sleek look with decent specs and the cheapest piece on the list.

Answer (score 2):

### [Asus](http://www.asus.com/Eee/Eee_PC/Eee_PC_1225C/) with Ubuntu 12.04

[image: image from vendor website]

<sup>image from vendor website</sup>

For a modern netbook, Asus have quietly launched its own 12.04 compatable netbook.

Let's hope its the first of many.

Comment: Looks interesting, I'd need something a bit larger - however, great to see another manufacturer try shipping something with Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick search on Dell's website for "Ubuntu" and got [this list.](http://search.dell.com/results.aspx?s=gen&c=us&l=en&cs=&k=ubuntu&cat=all&x=0&y=0)

Comment: Have you even clicked on any of those links in your list?  Because you can't customize them to get Ubuntu on those systems (the data there is old)