# Laptops that will work with Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, hardware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Who makes laptops for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32152/who-makes-laptops-for-ubuntu)

Following on from my last question 'Laptop with Nvidia Optimus' I am looking for a new (current) laptop with a decent supported graphics card (preferably NVidia but maybe ATI) to run Ubuntu on.
I need to know all the hardware will work, (I don't mind some tweaking to get things done).
I have searched online and most of the sites listing compatibility are out of date with both hardware and the versions of Linux that are being used.
Even though lots of work has been put in compiling the information the sites are virtually useless because of the fast pace of development in both hardware and software.

Probably the best to look is a site like this where there are lots of active users that keep up to date with both hardware and software.
What laptops are you all using (and are confident to recommend to others).

I have money to spend but after days and weeks of searching I can't find reliable info on which to make a purchase.
(recently NVidia Optimus has made things more difficult on the graphics card front)