# Where can I find computers that has a 100% support of Ubuntu?

Tags: laptop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which computers are guaranteed to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131/which-computers-are-guaranteed-to-work)

I want to buy a new computer but I want to know which computers will work without any issues with Ubuntu?

I want to make a safe buy and not have to google up any possible fixes, I want everything to just work.

Comment: And... now its a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/32152/who-makes-laptops-for-ubuntu, http://askubuntu.com/questions/131/which-computers-are-guaranteed-to-work