# Ubuntu preloaded laptops help

Tags: 12.04

I have been wanting a new laptop because of my slow vista desktop and i want a preloaded ubuntu laptop. I need help on what to buy because i am limited to about $1200 and i will be using this laptop for gaming with steam.

Comment: Please, see this thread [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/32152/who-makes-laptops-for-ubuntu).

Answer (score 1):

Visit this [UbuntuPre-installed list](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuPre-installed) .

Or You can choose the Best for yourself through this

[Ubuntu Certified hardware list](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/).

Visit their official Product sites for more info.