# Will LiveCD test results be aggregated into the laptop testing tracker?

Tags: hardware, live-cd, compatibility, testing

Marco Ceppi's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131/which-computers-are-guaranteed-to-work/133#answer-133) to a tangentially related question set me to wondering about the destination of all the tests that users run from the LiveCD menu.  There's a fairly comprehensive hardware compatibility test, at least as of 10.10, that seems geared towards accumulating a database of ubuntu-friendly models, components, and peripherals.

I must apologize for my vague description of this app; if someone knows what I am talking about and can provide the actual name of the menu item, that would be wonderful.  I just recall running it from the LiveCD before installation, after which point I switched over to OpenBox from gnome and haven't looked at the menu system since.

Marco's answer mentions the [laptop testing tracker](http://laptop.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/laptop), which seems like it could be a front end to this hypothetical DB.  However, there are currently only a few reports on that page.

Is this something we can expect to see made available in the near future?  Are collected test results available at a different page/site?  It would be a tremendously beneficial resource for the community.

Answer (score 1):

The tool is called Checkbox.  A new crowd-sourced "Ubuntu Friendly Hardware" program was recently announced, but I don't know if it will integrate with Checkbox.

http://victorpalau.wordpress.com/2011/04/28/introducing-ubuntu-friendly/

Comment: Cool, it sounds like they're aiming for it to be ready by 11/11.  Guess I'll "make a wish"..