# Should I buy a laptop with ATI/AMD on it?

Tags: ati, laptop, amd-processor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which computers are guaranteed to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131/which-computers-are-guaranteed-to-work)

I use Ubuntu on all my machines. I'm looking at a few laptops right now to replace a failing desktop:

1. A Lenovo with a AMD E 350 processor and integrated graphics (4 gigs of ddr3 ram)
2. Toshiba with an Athlon 2.2ghz with an ATI Radeon 4250 graphic chip (3 gigs of ddr3 ram)
3. And one machine is a Gateway with a Pentium P6200 2.1 ghz with integrated HD graphics (6 gigs of ddr3 ram)

I won't be gaming, but I will be using this laptop to stream high definition video to my 46" TV and I would like the video to be smooth as silk.
I won't be gaming at all.
Will either of the AMD laptops work "out of the box?"
Will the Gateway be a better choice?
Cheers!

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/131/which-computers-are-guaranteed-to-work

Answer (score 1):

I bought an hp dv6 which has a Quad Core and Radeon Dual Graphics and I was disappointed since trying install Ubuntu 11.10 on my laptop failed - either the laptop freezes or the screen goes black. My suggestion is not to get an AMD graphics card