# What P.C setup is guaranteed to work with ubuntu?

Tags: compatibility

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which computers are guaranteed to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131/which-computers-are-guaranteed-to-work)

Would that be the most common branded p.c and if so what model

I have a custom built P.C which has a 64 bit Gigabyte motherboard, and intel dualcore 2.5ghz processor and nvidia gforce 9400 card. So far I have managed to get 9.10 to install but have to use distro upgrade to get later versions. And 11.10 wont boot normally, I get a screen full stuff ending in checking battery state. The only way I can get that to work is to select previos versions then the first option in the grub. The main annoyance with 11.10 on my pc is startup manager cant be set, so it will always boot into error message as that is default. I like my set up to boot into windows7 by default or I choose ubuntu. Its just annoying so I have down graded to 10.04 and think I will have to stick with that till I need a new P.C or LTS runs out

Answer (score 3):

You can find a list of Ubuntu certified computers at http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I have found great support in top-to-bottom Intel based hardware. The Lenovo Thinkpad T410 for example which is what I am currently using has been great under the past two Ubuntu releases.

The [Ubuntu Friendly](http://friendly.ubuntu.com/) project (though currently in Beta) aims to provide information on hardware which works well with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know Asus is doing very well with Linux. As for graphics stick to Nvidia if you are going to buy a powerful VGA. ATI is only problems. Also pay attention to wireless card if your pc is going to have one. Check first that it's supported.

Comment: Let the ATI/NVIDIA wars begin. :) I've heard people argue one way or another, though I think the reality is that neither really gets a comfortable level of support from the manufacturers. It does sound to me like ATI had a lot of problems for the 11.10 cycle though, so you may want NVIDIA. Pick the Nouveau driver for stability, or the proprietary driver if you want better performance but possibly more bugs/freezes. The only graphics solution that I've found very dependable are Intel graphics, like on my laptop.

Comment: @ Warrioring64 the thing is that ATI stops supporting your card in the long run. I had an ATI card and after 3 years it just wasn't compatible with my Linux anymore. The Nvidia card I have now is 5-6 years old and still works amazingly on Linux. I have heard the same story from many people who are setting up computers as their job. You pay more for Nvidia but you are sure you won't need to buy a new card in the near future.