# What is the best laptop for ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: laptop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which computers are guaranteed to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131/which-computers-are-guaranteed-to-work)

I'm a Java, Ruby developer and looking for a new laptop to use Ubuntu on it.
Also,there have to be a good video. Please advise.

Comment: Look that any question of this kind will be closed... http://askubuntu.com/questions/131/which-computers-are-guaranteed-to-work

Comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1186/are-hardware-recommendations-considered-off-topic

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would select a computer from the [Ubuntu Certified hardware](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/) page.

Then deselect the options that are not laptops. You will also find some feedback on [Ubuntu Friendly](https://friendly.ubuntu.com/).