# Laptop on ubuntu-com logo

Tags: laptop

I want to ask one, maybe a little fun, question )

What laptop (model) is in the picture on the http://www.ubuntu.com/?
I see that this is Acer, but what model?

Does anybody know?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 is designed for all laptos,so you wont care about which laptop is in the pic :p

Comment: Yeah, I know. But it's a lot of problems with some laptops, for example I tried to configure ubuntu on my laptop during 3 months, I asked questions on many forums...  (oh my God, somebody has already dislike this topic =\ )

Comment: Related [Which computers are guaranteed to work?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/131/which-computers-are-guaranteed-to-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dude,its acer s3,(ultrabook) http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/aspire-s3-ultrabook

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the exact model of the image, but if you're plannig to buy a new laptop, please consider having a look at the [Certified hardware list](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/) in the official site.