# ubuntu compatible avec en CPU AMD A8-4500M APU with tm HD graphics 1.90 GHZ

Tags: installation, 13.04, compatibility

je cherche a Installer Ubuntu (n importe quel version ) mais compatible avec un CPU AMD A8-4500M APU with tm HD graphics 1.90 GHZ

Translation:

I’m looking for a Ubuntu installer (doesn't matter which version) that is compatible with a CPU AMD A8-4500M APU with tm HD graphics 1.90 GHZ

Comment: Salut, bienvenu a AskUbuntu. Ici ont parle que l'Anglais, donc ta question serai effacé dans quelques heures. De toute façon il y a déjà plusieurs [questions similaires](http://askubuntu.com/questions/131/which-computers-are-guaranteed-to-work).

Comment: Pour une bonne réponse, il est également important de savoir la quantité de mémoire du système a.  ||  For a good answer, it is also important to know how much memory the system has.

Answer (score 0):

Your hardware should work without any problem.

http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/component/dmi/4458/dmi:AMDA8-4500MAPUwithRadeon%28tm%29HDGraphics/